# PHP not able to set cookies through Nginx

Tags: php, cookies, nginx

I've got a PHP-fpm setup on nginx setup according to this article: http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/

PHP is not able to set cookies in any browser visiting the server. It seems nginx is not passing on the Cookie header to the browser. I [Googled around a bit](http://groups.drupal.org/node/26485#comment-91278), and found that I need to set `fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie` in the location/http block. I tried both blocks and it still doesn't work.

I'm looking for any help. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you posted your nginx configuration

Comment: Same problem, there was a `fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;` in my location block of nginx & that was my problem! Thanks, your question helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to post the config file as suggested by Ramon, but it seems like it's working now. There was a bit of ambiguity between the server names of two `server` blocks. I cleared that up, and its working fine now :D

Thanks!